# OAuth 2 + Attribute Based Encrytpion

Tags: authentication, web-applications, cryptography, oauth

Can I use Attribute Based Encryption (like CP-ABE scheme) and Oauth 2.0 to implement the Authorization, Confidentiality and Authentication (i.e. with FB, Google, Twitter etc.) in a web-application ?

Is there any example or framework ?
Is there any suggestion to use ABE with Oauth ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to use OAUTH with CP-ABE. Those materials are on different levels. In fact, the OAUTH standard doesn't mention encryption at all, it just requires HTTPS without specifying a SSL/TLS version or cipher suite. Also OAUTH is concerned with resource access, thus *authorization* (but often misused to authenticate objects).

From the CP-ABE perspective there is no logic either. The idea of PKI is to establish a secure and trusted channel, not to do authentication or authorization.

If I have misunderstood the question, please clarity.

**Update**

Yes it is possible, but still subject to research, and therefore I wouldn't put too much trust in the method yet. What the paper describes it possible, but I doubt it will be used on large scale.

Comment: I want to make a web-application to authenticate the users (i.e. from my local database, Facebook, Google+, Twitter, Linkedin, and more) and after this, when the user is authenticathed in this platform, he can encrypt "a message" or "a file". The encryption that I wish implement is CP-ABE because i don't want establish a secure channel but a secure content. With CP-ABE i wish encrypt a file for multiple users, and the users that have the right attributes can open and decrypt the file.

Comment: @JLo This is a complete different story than the topic describes. The whole encrypt-a-message is missing, you might want to add that.

Comment: Sorry but when I talked about Confidentiality I wished to say encrypt a message.

Comment: i.e. I found this pdf (http://datasys.cs.iit.edu/events/DataCloud-SC11/p05.pdf), but there isn't a practical example

Comment: -1 because of "The idea of PKI is to establish a secure and trusted channel, not to do authentication"

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but want to comment here.

The key feature of OAuth2 is to facilitate authorization

The key feature of ABE is to facilitate encryption using attributes that helps in achieving privacy.

[for confidentiality and authentication, explore something else].

Since authorization and encryption/privacy are different aspects of security, they can be combined in innovative ways [such as [this]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2087522.2087531).